# Nested codeigniter and how to get relative path of main codeigniter folder

Tags: php, codeigniter

I installed two codeigniter for desktop and mobile version. My directory structure is as follows:

```
 www/projectfordesktop/application
 www/projectfordesktop/uploads
 www/projectfordesktop/projectformobile/application
```

My problem is that when I upload files from mobile site I want my file to be uploaded in main codeigniter application `www/projectfordesktop/uploads`. So, I want to access main codeigniter application base_url to `www/projectfordesktop/projectformobile/`. How is it possible.

I made two project because it redirect to `m.project.com` when accessed from mobile. And when access from desktop `project.com`. Is it good idea. If not, then is there any way I can use seperate view for mobile and desktop. Please help. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For security and a bunch of other reasons you absolutely do not want the upload folder in your application folder. And if at all possible you want your application folder and system folder above the public root. The other consideration - its possible and in some ways desirable to rename your application and system folder. So if your public folder is www

```
 desktopapplication/www/
   mobileappliction/www/
          system306/www/
```

Now they are all safely above the public www, and they are labeled for what they are. Next you can have folders in the public folder, that contain the main index.php file for the specific application.

```
  www/projectfordesktop/index.php
  www/projectformobile/index.php
```

Open up the index.php file and redo the file paths to the application and system folder. Like

```
$system_path = '../../system306';
$application_folder = '../../desktopapplication';
```

The upload folder will now be either in www or one of the folders like projectfordesktop. Typically you would also put your css, js, etc files in there as well.

```
 www/projectfordesktop/upload/ 
 www/projectfordesktop/css/ 
 www/projectfordesktop/js/ 
 www/projectfordesktop/img/
```

Now - all the files which are public - are in a public folder. All the files which should be kept private - your application and system folder - are not public. And because you have labeled your application and system folder it makes it much easier to switch to different versions or revert back if needed.